# How to add next column to ListBox while using DataSource?

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say I have a `ListBox` called `animalList`. As `DataSource` I use following class:

```
class Animal
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private string description;

    public Animal(int id, string name, string description)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public int Id
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public string Name
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public string Description
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

I'd like to have 2 columns in `ListBox`: Name and Description. Is it possible to do so?
I managed to add one column like this:

```
List<Animal> animals = // LINQ sucking data from XML

animalList.MultiColumn = true;
animalList.DataSource = animals;
animalList.DisplayMember = "Name";
animalList.ValueMember = "Id";
```

but I cannot really figure out how to actually implement next column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the MultiColumn property can be slightly misleading.  The ListBox control does not support the type of columns you're looking for.

What MultiColumn actually does is "overflow" items into a new column instead of showing a vertical scrollbar.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn.aspx

Comment: I hate myself now. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: No problem.  It probably could have been named a little less ambiguously.